# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using bootstrap to create a web app. I am using rails 4.2.2 and heroku as my server. At first the carousel works fine. But after visiting another link on my site when I come back to the home page, the carousel is not working. I get the error on the chrome console.

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function

I have looked at other solutions given in the site, but nothing has worked for me so far. 
I am using the following code to load the js and jquery in my .html.erb file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: open your console(when your on that page), and see if bootstrap is even loaded, type $ press enter, type jQuery press enter, see if those answer, then type in the bootstrap variable, not sure what it is `bootstrap` maybe?  try `$.carousel` not sure what you use to load it, but you get the idea.  see what you can find out from the console.   I suspect the object is not available, and you need to include it somewhere else in your js code, maybe you have another js controller for the other page your on... etc..

Comment: 100 bucks says you're loading another version of `jQuery` after you include the bootstrap script - which is what causes the error. Only one version of `jQuery` per page, please.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Without seeing your code, and the console errors, its going to be difficult for anyone here to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: I am very new to this. Sorry if all this is supposed to be known to me. But I am getting the following error when I see the console for $jquery. jquery
VM121:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM121:1InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM63:145InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM63:137InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM63:118                                                                        How can I make sure that jquery and bootstrap is loaded properly?

Comment: if you copy pasted that error, then... you're incorrectly referring to jQuery as `jquery`. javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: When I type  jQuery on the console I get the output as function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)} but when I type bootstrap I get the output as VM3723:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined

Comment: are you using prototype?

Answer (score 0):

I made sure I ran all the commands as mentioned in the following link:https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails                                        Also, removed all the entries for adding bootstrap from my html files as they are not required here. Now the carousel is working even after coming back from the links. Only thing is on my chrome console, even now when everything seems to work fine, it is showing bootstrap is not defined. But everything seems to be working fine.